# What is the BigQuery schema for Google Shopping Search Query data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Google Analytics Google Ads Queries :
[image: Google Analytics Google Ads Queries]

Refer to the image provided.  How do you get Google Ads/Shopping Search Query data into BQ from Google Analytics? I'm using `trafficSource.keyword` and filtering for "`id==`" to get SKU level data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not all Google Ads data will be available in BigQuery after linking Google Analytics with Google Ads. Yes, on the webpage UI in Google Analytics there is a Google Ads section, but using the BigQuery Data Transfer Service to get Google Analytics data into BigQuery will have a limited selection of Google Ads data.

You can see in the docs here what metrics there are under trafficSource.
adwordsClickInfo nested fields:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Maybe, you can pull some of the data you are looking for with trafficSource.keyword for the keyword and trafficSource.medium, but I don't see in the docs anything aligned with Search Query.

If you want to have more data from Google Ads, you will need to set up a separate pipeline in BigQuery using Data Transfers within BigQuery for Google Ads which acts similarly to how you link Google Analytics with BigQuery. Please see the docs below for this.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer

Comment: Thanks, Edward. I have reviewed that documentation before. I'm not sure how to get the search term data at the product/SKU level through a Google Ads data transfer, what would be equivalent to the keyword id== parameter? We'll have to set up that connection and dig around. Also, in another thread a person hinted they may have found the query data in the gclid (trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId) which uses an ARRAY. Currently I'm trying to get the query right to see what data this schema contains. Thanks again!

Comment: For Google Ads Data Transfer, see the second page of the docs in below link. The data transfers give you partitioned tables with auto-generated views one for each type of Google Ads report. I see a Search Query Performance Report which is split into two tables: SearchQueryStats table and SearchQueryConversionStats table. See if the data here is sufficient. Link to docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transformation